# Describe the union and intersection of $n$ open neighborhoods of the same point

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Given real numbers $x, \delta_1,..., \delta_n, $ I am asked to describe

$$ \bigcap_{i=1}^n N(x, \delta_i ) \; \; \; and \; \; \; \bigcup_{i=1}^n N(x, \delta_i ) $$

where $N(x, \delta_i ) = \{ y: |y-x| < \delta_i \} $

for the first one, I know this set is the set of all points $y \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $|y-x| < \delta_i $ for all $i=1,...,n $. Is this what they are asking for? I am kind of confused.

Comment: Always try working gradually. For instance, try to find out what is the shape of the set $N_1=\bigcap_{i=1}^1 N(x,\delta_i)=N(x,\delta_1)$. Then you try to find out the shape of the set $N_2=\bigcap_{i=1}^2 N(x,\delta_i) = N(x,\delta_2)\cap N_1$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each of the neighborhoods in the union and intersection are about the same point $x$, we can describe these simply as

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^n N(x,\delta_i) = N(x, \min \delta_i)$$ and $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n N(x,\delta_i) = N(x,\max \delta_i).$$

The first can be explained by noting that if $y \in \cap N(x,\delta_i)$ then $|y-x| < \delta_i$ for all $i$. Thus $|y-x| < \delta_j$ where $\delta_j$ is the smallest of the $\delta_i$'s. This gives $\cap N(x,\delta_i) \subset N(x,\min \delta_i)$. For the other direction, if $y \in N(x,\min \delta_i)$ then $|y-x| <\delta_i$ for any $i$. Thus $N(x,\min \delta_i) \subset \cap N(x,\delta_i)$.

The second uses a similar argument.